# Vector Rotate random on two axis (geometry nodes)

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm learning a bit about geometry nodes, and they are great, but it's not always clear how to control them the way you want.

So, in the scene I'm trying to align the human figures in front of the scene, with a bit of randomness (maybe facing one point at the end?)

But I'm really struggling to make it work
[image: scene]

[image]

Any help will be appreciated! :)

Answer (score 2):

use attribute randomize rotation like this with vector:

[image]

If you randomize with float value, each axis will be randomized which you don't want. I think you just want just a z-rotation.

Example:

[image]